# Command Line Parameters?

Tags: command-line, printing, microsoft-publisher

Is there a way to print Publisher 2007 files on there own from Task Scheduler?
Maybe a third party program, or a command line parameter something like (Pub.exe -print40pages -server1//HP2050.drv -form2013.pub)

Answer (score 0):

Publisher has a command-line switch for printing that you could use in a script/task.

From Microsoft's [Command-line switches for Publisher 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/publisher-help/command-line-switches-for-publisher-2007-HA010169528.aspx):

> /p filename - Prints the file that you name, and then closes Publisher.